# renaming files to a new name folder using batch script

Tags: batch-file, rename

Have tried to rename files in a folder with this script, but its seems not to work

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET old=*.txt
SET new="c:\path to file that contains the listed names" 
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
   SET newname=%%f
   SET newname=!newname:%old%=%new%!
   move "%%f" "!newname!" 
)
```

what am trying to achieve is my script should pick set of listed names in a file and rename each file in the specified folder accordingly

Comment: Worked for me. What's your error?

Comment: i just edited the script maybe you should look again and see what the error is

Comment: as the subject stated, am trying to rename files stored in a folder with set of listed names in a file.

Comment: It does not work! And what type of error you have? Your computer crashes, the files are deleted or do you get an error message? Did you tried to echo some debug infos?

Answer (score 1):

test this script

```
 @echo off
    set prefix=new

    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.txt /b') do (
                                      set name=%%~Na
                                      set newName=%prefix%!name:~0,1!X!name:~1,2!!name:~3!
                                      ren "%%a" "!newName!%%~Xa")
```

Answer (score 1):

First you said you want to rename each file "accordingly" (accordingly to what?), and later in a comment you said you try to rename files "with a set of listed names in a file". This point cause several additional questions: Have this file one name in each line? Must the first file listed by `dir /b *.txt` match the first name listed in the file, and so on? Any other option? (Why do you use a `move` command to do a "rename"?).

Because the objective is not clear, we can not said if your code is right or not. However, this is what your code does. Suppose the first file is "firstFile.txt"; then this section:

```
SET newname=%%f
SET newname=!newname:%old%=%new%!
move "%%f" "!newname!"
```

is executed this way:

```
SET newname=firstFile.txt
SET newname=!newname:*.txt="c:\path to file that contains the listed names"!
```

Previous line replace from the beginning of newname until ".txt" (that is, the *entire* value) by `"c:\path to file that contains the listed names"`, so the next line is executed this way:

```
move "firstFile.txt" ""c:\path to file that contains the listed names""
```

that correctly should move the file into the given path even if it contains a pair of quotes at each side.

If the objective would be "Rename files in a folder to the names listed in a text file one-by-one", then you must do a *merge* between two lists: the file list created by `dir /b *.txt` and the name list stored in the file.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET old=*.txt
SET new="c:\path to file that contains the listed names" 
< %new% (for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b %old%') do (
   ren Read the next name from the redirected input file
   SET /P newname=
   ren "%%f" "!newname!" 
))
```

If this is not what you want, please clearly describe the desired process...

Comment: Aacini. you are very correct with the second option, am actually trying to rename files in a folder with names listed in a  text files one by one. so i took the second script you wrote out and ran it but added pause to see what the error was and the error i got is "access denied". any idea on why its not working?

Comment: Did you correctly write the name of the file in `SET new=` command?. Something like `SET new="C:\My Documents\Files\fileList.txt"`...